# Supply variable for title attribut in JSP

Tags: html, jsp

In JSP page I am using title attribute to display text when i mouse hover. i want to use same title text for multiple fields.

Is it possible, i can declare that String at one place and use it over and Over.

Is it possible I can use that string with some other place.

I have tried using scriplets (<%   %>) and include but not working. May be I am not sure how to call the variable as an attribute.

Answer (score 0):

There two ways to accomplish this.

The first option, which I recommend, is using JSTL to set the variable, then use an expression in the title attribute, like this sample JSP:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Expression in title attribute</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <c:set var="myTitle" value="This is my title text using JSTL set tag"/>
  <a href="yourpage" title="${myTitle}">test link</a>
  <br>
  <a href="yourpage2" title="${myTitle}">test link 2</a>
  <form>
   <input type="text" title="${myTitle}">
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

The second option would be if you cannot use JSTL for some reason.  You can use a scriptlet to set a variable, but generally scriptlets in JSP are frowned upon.  Here is the example JSP:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Scriptlet in title attribute</title>
 </head>
 <body>    
  <%
    String myTitle = "This is my title text using a scriptlet to set a variable"; 
  %>
  <a href="yourpage" title="<%=myTitle%>">test link</a>
  <br>
  <a href="yourpage2" title="<%=myTitle%>">test link 2</a>
  <form>
   <input type="text" title="<%=myTitle%>">
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Also, if you were going to use the same title text in several JSP files, you could add the text in an include file and then just have each JSP file include this file.  This would be beneficial as the actual text is in one location, if you needed to modify it you would not have to modify each JSP file.
For example, you could put this in a file named titleTextInclude.jsp:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<c:set var="myTitle" value="This is my title text using JSTL set tag from an include"/>
```

Then in your JSP file(s) you would just include the titleTextInclude.jsp file, and would use the ${myTitle} expression, like this:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Expression in title attribute with an include</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <%@include file="titleTextInclude.jsp" %>
  <a href="yourpage" title="${myTitle}">test link</a>
  <br>
  <a href="yourpage2" title="${myTitle}">test link 2</a>
  <form>
   <input type="text" title="${myTitle}">
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help someone in future Im replying here this was the first question I found on the topic. Use of attributes is the best possible solution.
jsp code snippet
`<title>${title}</title>`

**Wisdom: its safe to give a generic value using JSTL for the attribute.**